# python: set the color of a single line in a list view

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm doing some tests and create a list that displays the results of those tests in a gui

```
self.listCtrl1 = wx.ListCtrl(id=wxID_FRAME1LISTCTRL1, name='listCtrl1',
          parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(15, 24), size=wx.Size(808, 419),
          style=wx.LC_REPORT)
self._init_coll_listCtrl1_Columns(self.listCtrl1)

self.listCtrl1.Append([datetime.datetime.now(),action,result])
```

What I would like to do is to change the color of each item in the list based upon if the test passed or failed.  How is this done (if it can be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with SetItemBackgroundColor. Check the API for details: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html

Comment: Thanks, had to do self.listCtrl1.GetItemCount() first to determine the index, but then I was able to use SetItemBackgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

This should change bg colour of an item:

```
idx = self.listCtrl.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, datetime.datetime.now())
self.listCtrl.SetStringItem(idx, 1, action)
self.listCtrl.SetStringItem(idx, 2, result)
self.listrCtrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(self, item=idx, col='#0000FF')
```

you need its idx and wx.ListCtrl.Append will not return it.